# Read Rijndael encrypted file in memory itself to decrypt

Tags: vb.net, encryption, rijndael, binaryreader

I have a file which is encrypted using Rijndael encryption method. I want to decrypt in memory itself, instead of writing it to disk.

So I tried using `BinaryReader` to read the file. But how to use BinaryReader and read the binary file so that i can decrypt it. I tried using ReadString and and it gives `"Unable to read beyond the end of the stream."` error .

So how to read the file so that I can decrypt file using Rijndael method in memory itself.

Comment: Use `FileStream`, `MemoryStream`, `CryptoStream` and `StreamReader` instead. See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).

Comment: Is it fair to say this question is simply "how do I read a binary file in VB.NET?"?.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen `StreamReader`? Why?

Comment: @owlstead: if the plaintext is text... If it's binary then use `BinaryReader` but since OP wrote he/she tried to use `ReadString` I concluded the plaintext is text.